# How to put a php echo within a php echo + html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi guys I'm trying to output the name of the blog if it's on the home page and remove the link to the home page if it's on the home page by putting different css.

I've got the below currently:

```
if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'index' ) {

echo '<h4 class="site-title"><a href=".esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );.">.bloginfo( 'name' );.</a></h4>';
} else {
    // Some other CSS
}
?>
```

The code I'm trying to convert into an echo is as per below:

```
<h4 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h4>
```

The error I currently get is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/eol/public/wp-content/themes/shop-one-column/header.php on line 25
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` statement should be like this:

```
echo '<h4 class="site-title"><a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'">'.bloginfo( 'name' ).'</a></h4>';
```

Comment: Hi @RajdeepPaul - thanks heaps that worked, almost! Now unfortunately the link part of it isn't working and not linking to the home page?

How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1477592 Do `ctrl+u`(or `cmd + u`) and see what you have there in the link section of source code.

Comment: sorry I tried cmd + u in Chrome and in Sublime Text and it didn't come up with anything?

Also - if it helps, this is the link (a tag):

<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'">'.bloginfo( 'name' ).'</a>

Comment: @iamYPD Can you see the source code using `ctrl+u`(or `cmd +u` on Mac)? What it is showing there in link section?